# Avoid recording unwanted request in jmeter recorder automatically

Tags: jmeter, performance, http

Is there a way to not save Http Header requests send to a web site in JMeter recorder rather than recording and deleting manually?

Comment: Try using [Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732849-Chrome-Extension-Record).

Comment: Nice ! let me try it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this while creating the test script in JMeter. Please follow below steps:

- Add 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' under JMeter workbench when you
  start to develop the load test
- Uncheck 'Capture HTTP Headers' checkbox under 'Test plan content' section
  Perform the steps, HTTP headers won't be captured in your test actions.

I hope this solves your question! This approach can help you implement [test automation services](https://www.qasource.com/automated-testing-services) while you perform load tests on any application.